# are there special steps to for app ssl wildcard setup

Tags: app, ssl

I have SSL for in SAN . Is there any special setups for wildcard app setup in the IIS or load balancer?

The url is this and the page doesn't render the app web part.

```
https://extapp-b2da85d49e4598.apps-test.InsideNOV.com/AppBrightBanner/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fportal%2Dtest%2EInsideNOV%2Ecom&SPLanguage=en%2DUS&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E5223%2E1000&SPAppWebUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fextapp%2Db2da85d49e4598%2Eapps%2Dtest%2EInsideNOV%2Ecom%2FAppBrightBanner
```

certificate looks like below

CN - *.myNOV.com

### SAN names:

*.InsideNOV.com
InsideNOV.com
*.apps.InsideNOV.com
Apps.InsideNOV.com
*.apps-test.InsideNOV.com
Apps-test.InsideNOV.com

Answer (score 0):

I imported only 1 certificate that had all the SAN and re-did the binding and it worked. so there isn't a need for special handling.